# Symfony user authentication using Active Directory

Tags: php, windows, symfony1, active-directory, apache2.2

Is there a way to authenticate users in symfony apps using Active Directory? Can you please point out some documentation?

***edit***

What i need is to have a transparent login in my application. The user authenticates once at windows logon, then all applications should be accessed with the same credentials without being asked for the domain\username and password again.

I tried the following in a simple php script:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="my realm"');
  header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
  exit;
} else {
  echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
  echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```

but then i get the authentication form popped up. Is there any way to pass the header the credentials used at windows logon?

Thanks,
Radu.

Comment: It seems you have to look for some third-party libraries which can do the job.

Comment: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/vjGuardADPlugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by writing your own authentication callable for `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` (if you're using Doctrine). I'll quote plugins' [README](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/4_0_1?tab=plugin_readme) here:

> ### Check the user password with an external method
>
> If you don't want to store the
>   password in the database because you
>   already have a LDAP server, a
>   .htaccess file or if you store your
>   passwords in another table, you can
>   provide your own `checkPassword`
>   callable (static method or function)
>   in `app.yml`:
>
> ```
> all:
>   sf_guard_plugin:
>     check_password_callable: [MyLDAPClass, checkPassword]
> ```
>
> When symfony will call the
>   `$this->getUser()->checkPassword()`
>   method, it will call your method or
>   function. Your function must takes 2
>   parameters, the first one is the
>   username and the second one is the
>   password. It must returns true or
>   false. Here is a template for such a
>   function:
>
> ```
> function checkLDAPPassword($username, $password)
> {
>   $user = LDAP::getUser($username);
>   if ($user->checkPassword($password))
>   {
>     return true;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>     return false;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: But is there a way to automatically login the user using the credentials already provided by the user at windows logon?

Comment: AFAIK, no, there isn't. Only right way for me is to create filter similar to `sfGuardBasicSecurityFilter` which will log you in automatically as soon as he notices windows logon-related request headers.

Answer (score 1):

You could give the [bhLDAPAuthPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/bhLDAPAuthPlugin) a try?